# Excel formula to sum cell values between variable number of rows containing specific text string

Tags: excel-formula

### Have been looking for a formula that will add up cell values contained in variable number of rows delimited with same text string (A and End) and within fixed number of columns(A,B,C). Result to be 3 in example, but could be 4 if additional row added with cell value = 1. Thanks.
| A  | B | C

| 0  | 1 | 0
| 0  | 0 | 1
| 0  | 0 | 1
|End